# Multi parameter method in django viewset router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-viewsets

May i know how to setup method with multiparameter like=>

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
    def byshiftid(self, request,shiftid): 
        print("Hello World")       
        query = self.get_queryset().get(shiftid=shiftid)
        serializer = ShiftSummarySerializer(query,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this `shiftid` is the parameter.

Here is my router=>

```
router.register('shifts_mas', ShiftViewSet, base_name='shifts')
```

Normally my url will be like =>

```
api/shift_mas/
```

Now i would like to do like =>

`api/shift_mas/byshiftid/?shiftid="shift1"` something like that.

I try like that =>

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=True,url_path='/(?P<shiftid>)')
    def byshiftid(self, request,shiftid): 
        print("Hello World")       
        query = self.get_queryset().get(shiftid=shiftid)
        serializer = ShiftSummarySerializer(query,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But its always say 404 not found.

My requirement is to select the record by `shiftid`.So how can I setup the route like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using DRF, you might take a look at Django-filters. It offers an easy way to add filters to your views/viewsets:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProductList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('category', 'in_stock')
```

Then url requests filter the results:

```
api/production/?category='foobar'&instock='Y'
```

I've been using this in production for about six months with no issues.

Comment: I tried your way but i got this error: 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: s, h, i, f, t, d. I set filterset_fields=('shiftid')

Comment: @Jze You get that error when you don't have a trailing comma, change it to:  `filterset_fields=('shiftid',)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this part is called [**`Query string`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

```
api/shift_mas/byshiftid/?shiftid="shift1"
```

You can access the value of query string by:

```
shiftid = request.GET.get('shiftid', None)
```

So you don't need to define any url path and you can remove the extra parameter `byshiftid` method from  for this as well.